# How to detect correct GIT_DIR and GIT_WORK_TREE of the parent Git repository in a submodule

Tags: linux, git, bash, git-submodules

I'd like to implement a submodule in GNU Bash to check all GNU Bash scripts in the parent repository, excluding all submodules' Bash scripts.

I've already know that `git ls-files -z \*.bash` will do the job properly, the problem is I don't know how to detect the exact `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variables of the parent repository to export. 
 How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve this issue, simply change the working directory to the parent directory of the current GIT_WORK_TREE(which we should now be in the parent repository's worktree), then call `git worktree list --porcelain | grep worktree | cut -f 2- -d ' '` to fetch the parent repository's worktree.

This might not be a good method though.